# Index out of range in multidimensional array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

```
var tri = [[Int]]();
tri[0][0] = 321;
```

This code causes this error:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You're accessing the first element of the first subarray of the array. But your array doesn't contain any subarrays, so it crashes.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: @A.Bhakta Depends. Is `tri` only going to contain static data?

Comment: No, it will contain dynamic data.

Comment: @A.Bhakta So then you'll need to append empty subarrays to the main array, and then append to those subarrays. What exactly is this data? `tri` doesn't really say much